# Combining rows within the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, sql-update, sql-delete

I have Cart and Item tables as below

```
Cart
+---------+-------------+
| cart_id | customer_id |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           1 |
|       2 |           2 |
+---------+-------------+
```

and

```
Item
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| item_id | cart_id | product_id |   quantity |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 |       1 | AAAA       |          7 |
|       2 |       1 | BBBB       |          2 |
|       3 |       2 | AAAA       |          5 |
|       4 |       2 | CCCC       |          3 |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

I want to write query which will add items in one cart into another cart.
For example items in cart2 into cart1. After this query content of table should be like this

```
Item
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| item_id | cart_id | product_id | product_id |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 |       1 | AAAA       |          5 |
|       2 |       1 | BBBB       |          2 |
|       4 |       1 | CCCC       |          3 |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Table has such output because addition works in following way

1. Product AAAA was in both cart1 and cart2, so cart1 updated quantity=5 for item1
   and cart2 removed item3
2. Item2 did not changed because there is no such item in cart2
3. There is no item with product_id=CCCC in cart1, so it changed cart_id of item4 to cart1
4. Cart2 should be removed, because items in cart2 merged into cart1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you may be correct in your contention "I don't need to insert new values ..." the insert process provided by @GordonLinoff is **by far easier than any update** devised and likely to be much more understandable as a result. What's missing however is the removal of the now defunct cart, from both tables. That can be handled cascading CTEs(?) or a SQL function. Since I do not care for cascading DML CTEs I will provide a function.

```
create or replace function merge_carts(from_cart integer, to_cart integer)
  returns void
  language sql 
as $$
   insert into item(cart_id,product_id,quantity)
     select to_cart, product_id, quantity
       from item   
      where cart_id = from_cart
         on conflict (cart_id,product_id)
         do update set quantity = excluded.quantity; 
   delete 
     from item
    where cart_id = from_cart; 
   delete 
     from cart
    where cart_id = from_cart;            
$$;
```

Now once I know the cart_ids involved I just call the Merge_Carts function.

The critical issue is you making very sure your "anonymous user" identified as customer 2 is actually customer 1.  
See full case example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e186a56626993ad5ef2ca7e08dd45741).

Comment: Thanks for answer firstly,  I understood your point about : The critical issue is you making very sure your "anonymous user" identified as customer 2 is actually customer 1. I first implemented anonymous user's cart functionality by storing his items in cookie, but  code become cumbersome as I had to implement crud operations on client side as well. Do you have other idea how to implement this?

Comment: Since almost everything I do is on the back end (id DB) maybe take this with a-grain-of-salt. Add a column to the cart table say anonymous_user_id of data type uuid. When you have a anonymous user opens a cart generate a UUID on the client side. Store this in the cookie and in the cart table. Then when that user signs in (or signs-up if they did not already have an account) you can link the user_id with this UUID. That should give you the same unique identifier on both client and server. Merge the carts of this identifier.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to write query which will add items in one cart into another cart. For example items in cart2 into cart1.

If you want to do an "upsert" -- and `update` and `insert` in the same statement -- use `on conflict.

That starts with a unique key:

```
alter table item unq_item_cart_product unique constraint (cart_id, product_id);
```

Then:

```
insert into item (cart_id, product_id, quantity)
     select 1, product_id, quantity
     from item
     where cart_id = 2
     on conflict (cart_id, product_id)
          do update set quantity = quantity + excluded.quantity;
```

Comment: I don't need to insert new values, above situation happens when anonymous user adds items to cart and then logs into his account, because of that we need to merge two carts